# Creating blazor project but a problem occurred while building

Tags: asp.net-mvc, blazor

I'm trying to build a project using blazor and .NET but after I run this command

```
dotnet new blazorwasm -o blazor-web
```

I got this

```
Creating this template will make changes to existing `files:


`Overwrite   ./App.razor


`Overwrite   ./blazor-web.csproj


Rerun the command and pass --force to accept and create.
```

So after I built it I compile it using this command

```
dotnet build
```

but I got this error

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.5.0+d4cbfca49 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file `The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file`
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file `The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file`
```

You try to build the project from the wrong folder:

```sh
cd blazor-web
dotnet build
```

Comment: @aman when an aswer works you are supposed to accep it and vote up

Comment: i voted but since i have a few reputation number it hasnt been accepeted